# Check form submitted values in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

On my rails app I have a form on `/addfiles` where user can add file path in text boxes and this form is submitted to `/remotefiles`

I have created a route `match '/remotefiles' => 'main#remotefiles'`

and function in main controller

```
def remotefiles
    render layout: false
end
```

and add `remotefiles.html.haml` in views/main

how can I show these submitted values on remotefiles, I think it can be done with `render` but not sure how can I use it to pass form values and show them on view.

Is there a way to check form data in ruby on rails just like php `print_r` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form data is coming in via the `params` hash. The simplest way to respond with it would be

```
# MainController
def remotefiles
  render json: params
end
```

If your form contained fields named `foo` and `bar`, you'll see those as well as some parameters Rails adds:

```
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "controller": "Main",
  "action": "remotefiles"
}
```

If you want to render them into a real template, write the HTML into `app/views/main/remotefiles.html.erb`. Rails will by default render a template matching your controller and action, or if you want a different one you can instruct Rails to `render "path/to/other/template"`. Your template can access `params` too, but the more typical way to pass data into them is by setting instance variables in the controller.

```
# MainController
def remotefiles
  @foo = params[:foo]
  @bar = params[:bar]
end

# app/views/main/remotefiles.html.erb
<strong>Foo</strong> is <%= @foo %>
<strong>Bar</strong> is <%= @bar %>
```

Lastly, if you don't actually want to render the form data back to the browser, just inspect it during development, `Rails.logger` will print it into your server log.

```
# MainController
def remotefiles
  Rails.logger.info(params[:foo], params[:bar])
end
```

You should read up on how Rails works - the getting started guides are very clear and helpful. Here's [the one on rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).